# How do I stop grout in the corner of a shower from cracking?

Tags: bathroom, grout

I moved into a newly remodeled home. The walk-in shower walls are grouted. Now the corners have started to crack.

How do I slow down the cracking? Should it be caulked, or would that be a bad idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The corners of the shower walls should never have been grouted in the first place.  Corners are the most subject to movement and thus the most likely to crack, so they get caulked, not grouted.

Comment: I like to use a colored sanded caulk in this situaiton.  It looks very similar to grout. Sanded caulk comes in various colors. You should be able to get a close match to the grout.

Comment: Oh one other thing would it be a bad idea to caulk on to of the grout?

Comment: As opposed to removing it?  The grout is likely to crack further, and if you caulk over top of it, the caulk on top of the cracking grout could be affected by the cracking.  Better, IMO, to remove the grout as much as you can before caulking.